# Vegas Background jquery plug-in

Tags: jquery, plugins, background, slider

I am using the slideshow Vegas Background on a website http://www.freetimemagazine.net but the initial Upload time is too long, and you see the black background without elements for too long. I would like to place a still image of the background that is not part of the slider, but that it appears only in the initial time of loading. I tried to set the body background but I got nothing, I tried to set in the js plug-in a 'delay' faster for the first image of the slider, but I did not get anything ... How can I set a initial/default image?

Below is the code that controls the slideshow:

1) theme.js

```
/**
* Vegas background image slider
*/

$.vegas('slideshow',
{
   // delay: 5000,
    backgrounds: [
        { src: 'img/home/01.jpg', delay: 100, fade: 100 },
        { src: 'img/home/02.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/03.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/04.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/05.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/06.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
      //  { src: 'img/home/07.jpg', fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/08.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
      //  { src: 'img/home/09.jpg', fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/10.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/11.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
      //  { src: 'img/home/12.jpg', fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/13.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/14.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 },
        { src: 'img/home/15.jpg', delay: 5000, fade: 2000 }
    ]
})('overlay');
```

2) style.css

```
body  {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-size: 1.4rem;
color: #292929;
background: #000;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
$.vegas( 
     { src: 'img/home/01.jpg' }
);
```

Before

```
$.vegas('slideshow', {
    backgrounds: [ 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you figured this out already, but all you need to do is add a background image to the body of your website.

```
body {background: url('../img/yourimage.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
```

You may also consider optimizing your images a bit more. If you're trying load larger images they can take longer to load, not only that, but users are not visiting your site to wait around for the background and it could create a bad UX.